# How to access localhost over LAN ip in php?

Tags: php, html, lan

Hi guys i have three simple php pages `login.php`,`process.php` and `login_success.php`.The problem is that `login.php` and `process.php` is present in my `localhost:8080` but `login_success.php` is present at `192.168.1.36:8080` but on same lan.I am perfectly accessing my `login.php` but on clicking button it is not displaying `login_success.php`.I am using `XAMPP` server and it is installed in both the systems.The other thing is that i am accessing `logout_success.php` through url directly for e.g. `http://192.168.1.36/xampp/logout_success.php`. My code is very simple All my code is as follows:

Login.php:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
            <br/>
    password:<input type="password" name="pass"/>
            <br/>
             <input type="submit" value="Login!"/>
</form>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

   if($username == 'test' AND $password == 'test')
    {
      header('Location : http://192.168.1.36/xampp/logout_success.php');
    }
   else
    {
      echo "You have not logged in,username or password is incorrect!";
    }
?>
```

Login_success.php:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Logout Success<br>
    Thanks for using the Captive Portal...
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how to access `login_success.php`page.Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: What does it exactly show when you click the button?

Comment: It shows empty page..

Comment: Why is login_succes.php somewhere else??

Comment: It is a requirement for some specific reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a white space within the header call.

Change

```
  header('Location : http://192.168.1.36/xampp/logout_success.php');
```

to

```
  header('Location: http://192.168.1.36/xampp/logout_success.php');
```

---

**Entire Code:**

index.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
            <br/>
    password:<input type="password" name="pass"/>
            <br/>
             <input type="submit" value="Login!"/>
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

   if($username == 'test' AND $password == 'test')
    {
      header('Location: login_success.php');
    }
   else
    {
      echo "You have not logged in,username or password is incorrect!";
    }
?>
```

login_success.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    Logout Success<br>
    Thanks for using the Captive Portal...
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure the file names are right (lowercase). I have tried it on my test server and it seems to work. (http://jagmit.co.uk/test/php_login/)

**Also, i just would like to remind you that this is a bad example of how NOT to implement a login security system.**

Comment: It takes me to the required address after removing the whitespace but it is not displaying contents of `logout_success.php` ,it shows `web page is not available`.Should i need to add something in `logout_success.php`? !

Comment: just updated my post. Also, your php redirect is `logout_success.php` but your file is called `login_success.php`

Answer (score -2):

Use relative paths

```
header('Location : ./logout_success.php');
```